# Exclude goal from being applied to submodules?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have the following project structure:

```
root 
  |___ submodule1
  |___ submodule2
  |___ submodule3
```

and I have a custom plugin with a goal `custom-plugin:custom-plugin` that I sometimes want to run separately (not as a part of a phase).

When this goal is run as a part of the phase (that it is bound to) in the **root**, it doesn't get applied to submodules.

But when I call it separately as `mvn custom-plugin:custom-plugin`, it gets applied to the **root AND submodules**. I am, however, expecting it to get applied to the **root** project only.

Adding `--non-recursive` solves the problem, but is there any way to specify this directly in the `pom.xml`? To limit the plugin goal application scope to **root** only when running it separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you generally only want to run the plugin in the main POM, you can set

`aggregator = true`

in the `@Mojo` attribute in the plugin source code.